# CSS transform & opacity works on localhost but not on remote server

Tags: css

I have the same html file hosted on localhost as well as on a remote server. On localhost, CSS transform and opacity renders correctly, while the one on remote server doesn't render at all. Both are accessed using IE11 compatibility mode (due to legacy system needs). Opening F12 developer mode onto the remote server's page shows that the transform and opacity properties not being recognized in the styles tab (both shown with a wavy red underline in the developer tab).

Comment: Good that you have mentioned the problem, can you post the code too?

Comment: Very hard to tell without **any** code. How is your CSS referenced? Is it inline, in the head or an external sheet? If in an external sheet is the external sheet being loaded? Is this only an issue with IE or can you replicate it with any other browsers? When examining with dev tools are there any styles that are overriding the ones not working?

Comment: From memory "Compatibility Mode" is approx IE7 which does not support Opacity or Transform. Is this an "intranet" site, hence Compatibility Mode? This could explain the differing behavior based on the environment.

Comment: Thanks Jon P, apparently Compatibility Mode is the culprit. I've added the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Jon P's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50560627/css-transform-opacity-works-on-localhost-but-not-on-remote-server/50561056#comment88132263_50560627), I've checked the compatibility mode setting on localhost, and indeed it wasn't turned on. When I turn it on, transform and opacity failed to render accordingly.

Thank you all for the comments!